# oci_fetch_array returns false

Tags: php, oracle-xe

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM reunion';
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_execute($stmt);

echo '<pre>';

echo 'Reached'; // works

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
   print_r($row);  // prints nothing 
}

echo '</pre>';
oci_commit($conn);
oci_close($conn);
```

The above code prints nothing ! I have tested the connection and the table contains rows.

Comment: Did you cut something? There's a '}' missing. I don't see anything else wrong, though.

Comment: No, it is there ! It was my fault :/ Edited

Comment: 100% sure the connection works?

Comment: Yeah ! it is working since if I give a wrong table name ! it shows error !

Comment: Did you test http://php.net/manual/de/function.oci-error.php? PHP errors are all enabled as well?

Comment: Yes I have tested and the connection works !

Comment: I don't know why print_r() shouldn't work here, but try to echo $row[0] or $row ['column_name'].

Comment: I have tried echo also but no output ! do not know where going wrong !

Comment: Did you look into the source code of the page? Maybe it's just not displaying on your webpage, for whatever reason. I'm out of ideas! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105209/discussion-between-kaustav-ray-and-michael-rohrig).

Answer (score -1):

According to the official docs, `oci_fetch_array` returns an array containing the next result-set row of a query. Each array entry corresponds to a column of the row. This function is typically called in a loop until it returns `FALSE`, indicating no more rows exist.